# Generate the ticks of a graph

Tags: code-golf, array

A challenge many developers face when drawing a graph from scratch to plot some data is generating its ticks. In below graph, there are 6 horizontal ticks (1750, 1800, 1830, 1860, 1880 and 1900) and 11 vertical ticks (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 and 100).

[image: Relative share of world manufacturing output]

The horizontal bounds of the above graph goes from 1750 to 1900, which we'll call \$x_{min}\$ and \$x_{max}\$, respectively. For any \$x_{min}\$ and \$x_{max}\$ values, using \$n\$ ticks, there is a minimum multiple \$m\$ of a value \$s\$ that satisfies the following:

1. \$m \geq x_{min}\$
2. \$(m + s \times (n - 1)) \leq x_{max}\$; and
3. \$(m + s \times n) \gt x_{max}\$.

Let's suppose \$x_{min} = 0\$, \$x_{max} = 19\$ and \$n=4\$.

- Consider \$s=4\$. The minimum multiple of \$s\$ that is greater or equal than \$x_{min}\$ is 0, therefore \$m=0\$. While the second condition is satisfied (\$0 + 4 \times 3 = 12 \leq x_{max}\$), the third condition is not (\$0 + 4 \times 4 = 16 \not \gt x_{max}\$).
- Consider \$s=5\$. The minimum multiple of \$s\$ that is greater or equal than \$x_{min}\$ is 0, therefore \$m=0\$. Both the second (\$0 + 5 \times 3 = 15 \leq x_{max}\$) and the third (\$0 + 5 \times 4 = 20 \gt x_{max}\$) conditions are satisfied, therefore \$s=5\$.

Note that we need to minimize \$s\$: \$s=6\$ also satisfies all of the conditions, but we'll use \$s=5\$. In addition, since there could be more than one multiple of \$s\$ that satisfies all three conditions, we want also to minimize \$m\$ of the minimum found \$s\$.

Finding \$s\$ allows us to create \$n\$ equally-spaced ticks that can be used for our graph. The sequence goes from \$m\$ to \$m + s \times (n - 1)\$ with step \$s\$, so using \$s=5\$ as in the previous example, the generated ticks are \$\{0, 5, 10, 15\}\$. These ticks also gives the impression that our graph is sliding if we scale those properly, since they will only change if \$x_{min}\$ is a multiple of \$s\$. Below a gif that illustrates the generated ticks for \$(x_{min}, x_{max})\$ going from (0, 19) to (10, 29), with \$n=4\$.

[image: gif]

Another way of thinking about this problem is generating the ticks beforehand. Let's suppose \$x_{min} = 4\$, \$x_{max} = 21\$ and \$n=3\$.

- Consider \$s=5\$. This would generate the ticks \$\{5, 10, 15\}\$  and the next tick would be 20, which is not greater than \$x_{max}\$ (breaking the third condition). Note that here, \$m=5\$ since it's the first multiple \$m\$ of \$s\$ such that \$m \geq x_{min}\$.
- Consider \$s=6\$. This would generate the ticks \$\{6, 12, 18\}\$ and the next tick would be 24, which is greater than \$x_{max}\$ (satisfying all conditions). We could also use \$s = 7\$, but we want to minimize this value.

### Input

- Two real numbers `min` and `max` representing the minimum and the maximum values of a range, where `max` is greater than `min`; and one positive integer (`num`) representing the number of ticks.

The input is guaranteed to generate an integer `s`, so you should not handle `min = 0`, `max = 4`, and `num = 3` for example.

### Output

- A sequence of equally-spaced numbers with length `num` representing the ticks of a graph based on the previous explanation.

### Test cases

```
# from gif
0, 19, 4 -> [0, 5, 10, 15]
1, 20, 4 -> [5, 10, 15, 20]
2, 21, 4 -> [5, 10, 15, 20]
3, 22, 4 -> [5, 10, 15, 20]
4, 23, 4 -> [5, 10, 15, 20]
5, 24, 4 -> [5, 10, 15, 20]
6, 25, 4 -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
7, 26, 4 -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
8, 27, 4 -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
9, 28, 4 -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
10, 29, 4 -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
11, 30, 4 -> [15, 20, 25, 30]

# m can be negative
-10, 1, 3 -> [-8, -4, 0]
-9, 2, 3 -> [-8, -4, 0]
-8, 3, 3 -> [-8, -4, 0]
-7, 4, 3 -> [-4, 0, 4]
-6, 5, 3 -> [-4, 0, 4]
-5, 6, 3 -> [-4, 0, 4]
-4, 7, 3 -> [-4, 0, 4]
-3, 8, 3 -> [0, 4, 8]
-2, 9, 3 -> [0, 4, 8]
-1, 10, 3 -> [0, 4, 8]

# num can be 1
0, 3, 1 -> [0]
1, 4, 1 -> [3]
2, 5, 1 -> [3]
3, 6, 1 -> [4]
4, 7, 1 -> [6]
5, 8, 1 -> [6]
6, 9, 1 -> [8]
7, 10, 1 -> [9]
8, 11, 1 -> [9]
9, 12, 1 -> [12]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins. [Default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/91472) apply.

Comment: If s were restricted to integers, this would all make sense, but if s can be rational I'm very confused how it is determined. For example, in the test case `0,4,3`, why is `s=5/3` chosen, when, say `s=3/2` is smaller and would also satisfy all conditions? (In fact, there is no minimum value of s which satisfies that test case since any s in the half-open interval `(4/3,2]` would work). I'd recommend requiring s to be an integer to make this challenge well-defined.

Comment: Love the visuals!

Comment: @kops You're right, my mistake. Restricting `s` to integers.

Comment: You should also specify what to do on invalid test cases, i.e. those with `max-min-1<num`. The easiest thing is to guarantee inputs will have a solution but you could also require answers to output a falsy or otherwise distinct value in case of invalid input.

Comment: So if it were using the algorithm then the original graph (1750-1900) would have its six ticks at `[1771, 1794, 1817, 1840, 1863, 1886]`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, those would be the correct ticks. The first graph is just to illustrate what a tick is.

Comment: In the 2nd to last test case, eg, -- `8, 11, 1 -> [9]` -- would 8 be a valid result us well, with assumed step size `4`.   1. `8 <= 8`, check.  2. `8 + 4*(1-1) = 8`, which is less than `11`. Check.  3.  `8 + 4 = 12`, which is greater than `11`. Check.

Comment: Indeed, by "there is a minimum multiple  of a value  that satisfies the following", shouldn't the 9 (the expected output) be incorrect, since it is not minimal?  8 is lower while still satisfying the 3 conditions?  Is there a constraint I'm missing?

Comment: @Jonah The constraint you're missing is that we must also minimize s. Note that in the (0, 19, 4) example, s = 4 is invalid, s = 5 is valid and s = 6 is also valid, but we pick 5 because it's the minimum. For the (8, 11, 1) example, even if s = 4 (with m = 8) is valid, s = 3 also is (with m = 9). The first condition is valid, since 9 >= 8. The second condition is also valid, since 9 + 3 * 0 = 9 <= 11. The third condition is also valid, since 9 + 3 * 1 = 12 > 11. If we go one step back and pick s = 2 (with m = 8), the third condition will not be satisfied, therefore s = 3 is the expected value.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  So it seems we are minimizing both `m` and `s`, but that minimizing `s` takes precedence (I think this is implicit in the 8,11,1 example per my previous comment and your last comment).  I think that should be explicit.  Currently the problem says "minimum multiple  of a value  that satisfies the following" and also, re: `s`, that "we want to minimize this value."  But (afaict) it doesn't state what should "win" when mimizing `s` and minimizing `m` conflict, as in the 8,11,1 example.

Comment: You're correct, we must first minimize `s` and then - since there could be more than one multiple of `s` that satisfies all three conditions - minimize `m`. I tried to explain this by making a step-by-step example where I first found `s` and then found `m` for that `s`, but I'll make it more explicit, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you.  I have now fixed my own answer so that it's passing all test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>30 28</sup>  38 bytes

```
1 :'](]*i.@u+>.@%),(]+0 0-:|~)u>.@%~-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZPNaoNAGEX3eYpLoajNKM6PPyOkhBa6Kl10LyENpk2h6abpquTV7Yx@MyLILEQ494z63Rk/@5ssOmLTIAJDjsZcaYbH1@ennqOJ2ri9O2Xby/o@294mLG7XOfK0@bsmF0uuadQnq@7w8Y04ZygYuLnxIkHagGvECsfEPJIUnzOIfHBETg4POJwcEXAEOTLgSHJUwFHkFM6ZBHONg4mCpDIklSRVIakiqQ5JNUk6JLmyuW97MhjkOJ70dZu@Vy8PGfCFw/6Mtw7n7n3/c/rtaPWuZtgpcybGvUQs7brd9Pi5IJygl3Ppcj/pkDGoIVYurhbjwsXlYly6uFiMKxf7jbcRQz2ktUvlUqpdKpZS04brhfo8X3yh3C1IsLHz89m/IC1VRPmMFkT9K5WlJVH/maWlFVE1ozVR30dtqSbqS9SW2hn47KCOmBOejqYYuCCu0f8D)

This is a J adverb modifing `n`, the number of ticks, and taking the max and min as left and right args, respectively.  Called like:

```
19 (4 f) 0
```

- `u>.@%~-` Calculates step size by dividing `n` into the difference between the max and min.

  - `,(]+0 0-:|~)` Adds one to the step size if the step size evenly divides both endpoints.
- `]*` The step size times...

  - `i.@u` Produces range `0..n-1`
  - `+` Add elementwise to...
  - `>.@%` The ceiling of `>.@` the min divided by the step size `%` -- adjusts so the first tick starts where we want.

Comment: I think this produces the wrong output for 4 steps from 4 to 20 - I suspect the correct answer is 5, 10, 15, 20 but this gives 4, 8, 12, 16, which leaves room for a fifth step.

Comment: @Neil After clarification with OP, I've fixed the issue and this now passes all test cases.  Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't think to check before but I noticed that you don't always minimise `s` when you could e.g. 4 ticks from 17 to 55 should be 24, 32, 40, 48 but you output 20, 30, 40, 50.

Comment: Ah, nice spot.  I can just try all `s` ofc if need be, but I'd love to know if there's still a closed form way to solve this.  It amounts to solving modular equations in `x` of the form `C <= (((A mod x) + B)/x) < C+1`.  Do you happen to know if this is possible?

Comment: I have no idea sorry, I couldn't find a better way than just trying all values of `s`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≔¹ε≔…·⌈θηδＷ⁻Ｌδζ«≦⊕ε≔…·⌈∕θε∕ηεδ»Ｉ×δε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY0/C8IwEEdn8yk6XkAHobo4iS4FKyJ@gdgcyUF62iatUPGzx/gHFAeHGx73473KqrY6KRdjwecubLv6iC00ciG@2f7wkHjpPRmG6TjDDxVcuc5Tj3vFBmGF5IhN8o0zm06n5cWSwwxK4s7DBtkECzr9BimzqxiV6vxxtVgjB9Svxuh/ZE09aYTmMU6@N9o3PtI3sWuJA6yUD3CgGj081VIuYpzOxSwXeZz07g4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: I tried and failed to find some sort of formula, so brute force it is.

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input the minimum, maximum and ticks.

```
≔¹ε≔…·⌈θηδ
```

Start with a step of 1 and ticks from the ceiling of the minimum to (the floor of) the maximum.

```
Ｗ⁻Ｌδζ«
```

Repeat until we get the desired number of ticks.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Increment the step.

```
≔…·⌈∕θε∕ηεδ
```

Divide the ends by the new step size and list the integers in that range.

```
»Ｉ×δε
```

Multiply those by the step to get the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> <s>69</s> 59 bytes

*Edit: <s>+24</s> +14 bytes to fix bug pointed-out by Neil & ophact*

```r
function(l,h,n){while((t=-l%/%T+1)+h%/%T-n)T=T+1
T*(1:n-t)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNNT4MwGL7zK5qYZeDaSD8oxWQmXj142k13QMIGkXXJZHow/nZ8i9DVbFIvZM/HHt4@vD10bV28vi27zVEXbb3XYYMrrKPPj6puyjBsl6SZ3cxWCxotKvOD6Gi1BBisrkN6q0kbfXVXaHPY79BjWTdBHxcKjFiMkYjQFSJ36CnBiAKmieHXg4mmGCWJ42ICc4ZFjIVaB0XehvNnPY@CIf5hr/O2yjW6b5pc24zE5GYxPOWYQ9OUYppmAlMFL6EKIqmSHB5KXkje1pshrs9yJgJsR7dj/@dsDAD1mTgA5jOZKrnPZIDwmSQAt@6TwwijCz4Kk16XApB6XVAlU16XYVnmt0Gf3C3@ZDHC7@@6QwVsykuJdLnN2/q9HEJInw3@MYTAfASqsy0RM/SkAQg@aTDFuAYjAmV12W/V3zqIckoHnE7pMJ1y9LgfR1kZTpdNyPRnd851t199tA3T092BF1P7N@e@CIfnzhVJLvG8P73lhXMRUoeXzu6rS7zsj2l55Sx4vwSjkDk7bXbsXDAxzBEoW3ff)

**Ungolfed version**

```r
ticks=
function(l,h,n){        # l=low, h=high, n=n ticks
  d=1:(h-l+1)           # d=range of possible values of s to try
  s=match(n,(floor(h/d)-ceiling(l/d)+1))
                        # calculate s by trying each value of d
                        # until floor(h/d)-ceiling(l/d)+1 is equal to n
                        # (golfed: match(n,h%/%d+-l%/%d+1))
  a=ceiling(l/s)*s      # calculate a=start value (golfed: --l%/%s*s)
  return(a+(1:n-1)*s)   # output ticks (golfed: s*(1:n-1--l%/%s))
}
```

Comment: I don't think this minimises the step, e.g. 17 to 55 in 4 steps can be done with multiples of 8.

Comment: I'm not sure `floor((h-1)/n)+1` is a correct formula for `s`. It is not always the "optimum" value.

Comment: @Neil & ophact - Thanks for spotting that!  I was over-reliant on the original test-cases (that have now been fixed), and should have thought-through the spec better.  I *think* it should be fixed now...

Comment: @ophact - Thanks: see comment above (& please let me know if you find another bug...)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
r/ḍ@ƇⱮJ$L⁼¥ƇḢ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a pair of numbers, `[xmin, xmax]`, on the left and an integer, `n`, on the right that yields a list of ticks.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//ci/huI1Axofisa5KJEzigbzCpcaH4bii////WzE3NTAsIDE5MDBd/zY)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##TdCxysIwFAXgV8ngWLE3bdN0EWfxBSR0dBEnNzf9FycXJwddBHERwU3BSdH3aF8knlhz80Mh/QjhnHvHo8lkZu20U11Xvfeyvpz7rUG9uD8O72V13dvX/Xns1H@n17q6bXDiG7tjvhXtrqjnu6G1xpg4ElSUkUhLERlDkZAxS0LESiDJSqGElUEpS0EZK4cUS0M5q4B0SEcZ@a8M2iShTdtduzpJQ/c2SLs/Vu4esdAnC0JXFYQ58iDMqIMwfxGENhQz4yaP/NpShmzSyC9NMX5Z5FemGapJIr@wbxD5hRGxMDTJr8oP).

#### How?

```
r/ḍ@ƇⱮJ$L⁼¥ƇḢ - Link: list, bounds; integer, n:
 /            - reduce (bounds) with:
r             -   inclusive range -> [xmin..xmax]
       $      - last two links as a monad - f([xmin..xmax]):
      J       -   range of length -> [1..(xmax-xmin)+1]
     Ɱ        -   map across that with:
    Ƈ         -     filter keep those for which:
   @          -       with swapped arguments:
  ḍ           -         divides?
           Ƈ  - filter keep those for which:
          ¥   -   last two links as a dyad - f(potential tick list, n):
        L     -     length (potential tick list)
         ⁼    -     equals (n)?
            Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
(x#y)n=[[i|i<-[x..y],mod i s<1]|s<-[1..],div y s+div(-x)s<n]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJNboMwEIX3nMJJIwUUQzH/VJAT9AbICyRQa5U4UUAVRLk7HQ@FVA1ePb/vGWbs8WfZftVNM45m/zJYMi8KcReZXfSOM3B6OldEkDZj/N4CZI7DaSW@yUDaA6hp91abSb7ZuOOpFDKvzgYxBT1bmd1eSmm@5vvj3sp2x4@6exeyNkhTd0VPByp5fq3Larcv9m9Cio6Iw2HLt7iB3KasK0VD4I@Xq5Cd@dtgfqP4Pb1ZBlFFR5cSllISEPtICjAheMVCbjBKPHeOFq4gNzwQpsl8EE@TBSC@JlMSaLIIJJyzR6AoN2KQSBcmILEuhJN7iS5U3ku1KRzfX67nkSjKDRu3wxpTG2rYcDQVqJJrHJb@Gle9L1wx8IAjHNUTBhatYFjFKxgKJjN2sU4CFNpLnymbBvIPu9g1myA@mWC2Pr6S8I/1sbnJBvgW4tlGOP7kj42wi8kmOGO8UvQpjlVNYPFqrzd75vEf)

The function `(#)` takes the minimum value `x`, the maximum value `y` and the number of ticks `n`.

### How?

The problem is equivalent to finding
$$
\min\left\{s\ge 1:\left\lfloor\frac{x_{\text{max}}}{s}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{x_{\text{min}}}{s}\right\rceil=n-1\right\}.
$$

Since we are guaranteed that an answer exists, it is sufficient to find
$$
\min\left\{s\ge 1:\left\lfloor\frac{x_{\text{max}}}{s}\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{x_{\text{min}}}{s}\right\rceil<n\right\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```js
(a,b,n)=>(g=s=>(x=s*Math.ceil(a/s))+s*(n-1)<=b&x+s*n>b?[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>x+s*i):g(s+1))(0)
```

I will golf this later; could not find a suitable replacement for `Math.ceil`.

*-2 bytes thanks to my own golfing efforts.*

## Explanation.

This is an implementation which simply follows what is asked in the question. The function is recursive and will call itself with `s+1` if the conditions are not satisfied.

### commented

```js
(a,b,n)                         // declare parameters: input a, b, n
=>                              // start of arrow function expression
(g=                             // assign function expression to g
s=>                             // declare parameters: s
(x=                             // assignment expression: assign value to identifier x
s*Math.ceil(a/s))               // s multiplied by ceiling of a over s
+s*(n-1)<=b                     // speaks for itself
&                               // bitwise and (saves one byte)
x+s*n>b                         // speaks for itself
?                               // if above conditions satisfied, return
[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>x+s*i) // array of n elements each filled in with x + s times i
:                               // otherwise return
g(s+1)                          // call with s+1
)                               // closing bracket
(0)                             // IIFE: initial call with s=0.
```

And "fun fact": when s is 0, we get `NaN` (`Infinity * 0`) as the value for `x`, which makes it quietly fail. However, this is not noticed as the function increments `s` due to unsatisfied conditions.

Comment: ... well you could always start with `s=1`, could you not?